# Saving data(JSON) from external API to Ruby on Rails DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, api

I would like to save temperature and location from https://openweathermap.org/api in my Ruby on Rails 6 app.

Following this: https://dev.to/juzqrios/how-to-make-api-calls-in-rails-26l9 guide we end up with something like this:

**View**

```
<h2>Search for world weather by location</h2>

<%= form_with(url: search_path, method: "get", local: true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:location, "Enter Location name:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:location) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<% if @response %>
  <div>
    <%= @response.body %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
 def index
  if params['location']
   @response = Openweather::Search.by_location(params['location'])
  end
 end
end
```

**Routes**

```
get '/search' => 'search#index', :as => 'search'
```

**API Service /app/services/openweather.rb**

```
module Openweather
 class Search
  def self.by_location(location)
    Faraday.get 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + location + '&appid=' 
   + ENV['API_KEY']
  end
 end
end
```

Everything works fine, JSON is returning.
Then I did standard scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold SearchTemperature temp location
```

I removed from generated form field with temp

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :temp %>
    <%= form.text_field :temp %>
  </div>
```

Because I want to populate my DB with temp coming from Openweather JSON.

Sample JSON looks like this:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

And modify my **create** method in controller to:

```
  def create
    response = Openweather::Search.by_location(params['location'])
    @search_temperature = SearchTemperature.create(temp: response['main']['temp'],
    location: params[:location])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @search_temperature.save
        format.html { redirect_to @search_temperature, notice: 'Search temperature was 
         successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @search_temperature }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json:@search_temperature.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end
```

now when I try to submit my form where there is only location field I get this error:

**TypeError in SearchTemperaturesController#create**

**no implicit conversion of nil into String**

```
  class Search
    def self.by_location(location)
      HTTParty.get 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' 
      + location + '+ '&appid=' + ENV['API_KEY']
    end
  end
```

I guess, that error comes from fact, that there is no data and its just nil.
How can I do that? Why my controller isn't fetching data?
What am I missing in this code?

If I add **method: :get** to my **_form.html.erb** there is no error but also nothing saves in DB. I think there is a problem.

Help me guys, where should I start to learn how to solve that?
My API key is fine.
Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

The issue was caused by using `params[:location]` instead of `search_temperature_params[:location]`. Now it is working!

Comment: You're saying `I removed from generated form field with temp`, what does this mean exactly? If you've removed the `temp` field then why are you using it as `response['main']['temp']`, how this came?

Comment: Also if you're run a scaffold on `SearchTemperature`, your `white_list` params will be different if you're directly using `params[:location]`, so even if you send a form `params[:location]` will always be nil. Instead use `search_params[:location]`(whatever your white_list paramater name is replace it in place of `search_params`)

Comment: `no implicit conversion of nil into String` where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: @cdadityang I removed field with temp because it is suppose to be seeded with data coming from API JSON. `response['main]['temp']` is just to fetch "current temperature" from returning JSON.

Comment: @AmitPatel I got this error after I submit my `_form.html.erb`. Right know there is only :location field, because I want temp to come from API JSON.

Comment: @cdadityang YESS! In my create controller instead `params[:location]` I used `search_temperature_params[:location]` and now it is working. Thank you!

Comment: @debicky yayayay!